# Unity Changing GUI Colors / Slider Color / Label Color

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

i have a Settingsscript for a small simulation.

The BackgroundColor of the camera is black. When i have a GUI.HorizontalSlider with a Label i need to change the Slidercolor. Otherwise you can not see it well.

Can someone tell me where and how to set these Colors? "ContentColor", "BackgroundColor" are not working..

My Code:

```
 private int planetObjectsCount = 1;          // number of objects in the next scene
private int skyObjectsCount = 1;            // number of objects in the next scene
private int spaceObjectsCount = 1;          // number of objects in the next scene

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.color = SetGUIColor(); // Give GUI Elements a default Color

    planetObjectsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(GUI.HorizontalSlider(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 2 / 8), planetObjectsCount, 1, 300));        // The Slider Element - store the value
    skyObjectsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(GUI.HorizontalSlider(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 4 / 8), skyObjectsCount, 1, 100));             // The Slider Element - store the value
    spaceObjectsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(GUI.HorizontalSlider(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 6 / 8), spaceObjectsCount, 1, 100));         // The Slider Element - store the value

    GUI.Label(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 3 / 8), "Objects on the Planet: " + planetObjectsCount.ToString());          // The Label for the Slider
    GUI.Label(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 5 / 8), "Objects in the Sky: " + skyObjectsCount.ToString());                // The Label for the Slider
    GUI.Label(GetGuiRect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height * 7 / 8), "Objects in Space: " + spaceObjectsCount.ToString());                // The Label for the Slider

    if (GUI.Button(GetGuiRect(Screen.width * 0.85f, Screen.height / 2), "Build"))               // Menu Button
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("planetObjectsCount", planetObjectsCount);                   // Store the values to the PlayerPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("skyObjectsCount", skyObjectsCount);                             // Store the values to the PlayerPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("spaceObjectsCount", spaceObjectsCount);                     // Store the values to the PlayerPrefs
        LoadScene("Ingame");                                                                // Load the simulation
    }

    if (GUI.Button(GetGuiRect(Screen.width * 0.15f, Screen.height / 2), "Back"))        // Menu Button
    {
        LoadScene("MainMenu");                                                              // Back to MainMenu
    }
}

internal Rect GetGuiRect(float xPos, float yPos)                // Return a Rectangle for GUI Elements
{   
    float rectWidth = Screen.width / 5;
    float rectHeight = Screen.height / 10;

    xPos -= rectWidth / 2;
    yPos -= rectHeight / 2;

    return new Rect(xPos, yPos, rectWidth, rectHeight);
}

internal Color SetGUIColor()                                    // Set the GUI Color
{
    return Color.cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want.
But I believe you will fix your problem by using [GUIStyle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUIStyle.html) or [GUISkin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html).
Through GUIStyle you can change a lot of properities as the Font you will use and its color. So you create it and set a GUI component to use it. At GUILabel, for instance, you can pass the GUIStyle as the third parameter:

```
public static void Label(Rect position, string text, GUIStyle style);
```

And the GUISkin is a collection of these GUIStyles divided in all the UI components, so that you can create a whole new UI style.

However, I think you should know that Unity also provides a whole [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html), that you can twitch without needing code and quite frankly is way better then using OnGUI. To exemplify, here are the links of the Unity manual teaching how to created the [Slider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Slider.html) and the [Label](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) with it.